# pagination within the facebook API (photos)

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm currently developing a facebook app that needs access to a users photos. It needs to loop through all of the users active photos however I'm having some trouble with the pagination aspect of the feed. I get results from the API like

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 10151796309135076
                    [from] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Daniel Benzie
                            [id] => 762525075
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

obviosuly the above is an excerpt and then down the bottom there is a section for next and previous pages.

```
[previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/762525075/photos?access_token=xxxxxxx&limit=25&since=1338985293&__previous=1
[next] => https://graph.facebook.com/762525075/photos?access_token=xxxxx&limit=25&until=1332002972
```

this is always set- does anyone know the best way to loop through the photos in this case? thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep calling the `next` url until there is no more `data`

```
while ($some_photos['data'])
{
    $all_photos = array_merge( $all_photos, $some_photos['data'] );

    $paging = $some_photos['paging'];
    $next = $paging['next'];

    $query = parse_url($next, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    parse_str($query, $par);  

    $some_photos = $facebook->api(
        $user_id."/photos", 'GET', array(
            'limit' => $par['limit'],
            'until'  => $par['until'] ));
}
```

Comment: thanks for this - started doing this and I was getting a CGI error due to timing out - I started using the url &limit instead for facebook photos - I set the limit to 2000 using the example url:

https://graph.facebook.com/285900771/photos/?access_token=xxxxx&limit=2000

however only 283 photos are returned - i have definitely requested friends_photos in the feed and I can even see some photos from other users this user is tagged in. The user in question is tagged in 2642 photos so i guess I was just expecting more results. Do you have any ideas? thanks